# How can i apply display:flex on angular component?

Tags: css, angular

I am having the following html layoyut.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfiey8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

I need to have on the `parent` class `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` so input will be always next to the numbers on the left.

But when i put the numbers html layout in separate component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g53hgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

I manage to style the HTML from the parent component throught the `:host ::ng-deep` selector.

But the css class

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

does not work like in the first example where the HTML was not in the component itself.

I am stuck on this long time. How can i make `display:flex` on parent class to be equal like in the first example ?

Answer (score 0):

move your `parent` css class on to the component tag like this

```
<div>
   <app-numbers class="parent" [arr]="arr"></app-numbers>
   <input />
</div>
```

also if you already have a separate component for *number* then move the `.number` styles to the css file of this component, no need to write it using ng-deep

Comment: I need the input to be inline with the numbers component. The way you suggested - the input is under the numbers component.

Answer (score 0):

Move the css into number component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jlkeea

number.component.css

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.number {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

app.componet.css

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

this way you do not break view encapsulation as well

Comment: The stackblitz you provided - the input is not inline with the numbers component

Comment: I need the input to be inline with the numbers component, like in the first example

Comment: oh had to resize the example to see it remove flex-direction:column from parent

Comment: In your stackblitz i can't find any - flex-direction:column css. Can you please edit it

Comment: i just fixed it so you might have checked after i saved.

Comment: Henric it is not displaying withj flex; It is not like in the first example.

Comment: Your input is inline but it stretches on the whole height and take places so the numbers don't take width 100%

Comment: ahh i see, not sure you can do this without breaking up the component it self then, cause the component it self is a dom element, if thats the case you break up number to be single value elements and iterate over them like you did with the div. Or you could just move the input into the compoenent

Comment: Yeah. i am stuck on this one day.... i am making library where because of the separation of the concerns i don't want to mix the input togerher with the chips component.... :(

Comment: If its part of an component where the input is required i would move the input into the numbers, i just updated the link again.

Comment: It is the same as my first exampl.I know that that will work